# I don't know how to interpret this line 死んだと知らさせるより受け入れがたいから

Tags: translation, interpretation, particle-より

I don't understand very well what a character wants to say...For context, this character is on the verge of dying, he was cursed and had only a day to live and tries to find the one who cursed him.
While searching, he gets a phone call from a friend but doesn't answer because they don't want the friends to worry, for they don't know that he got cursed.

Character's inner thoughts: 悪いな…心配かけて。でもごめん…あと何時間で死ぬ…なんて。
**死んだと知らさせるより受け入れがたいから…**

I'm having trouble with that line I bolded, because even though I broke it down, I don't think I'm interpreting it well.
**"Because it's more unacceptable than telling them I'm dead".**
I don't think this this sounds right, what is he trying to say? That he'd rather have the friends believe he died instead of actually telling them that is about to die so that they won't get worried?
Is my interpretation of the line somewhat good?
Thank you in advance for those who could help me out with it!

Comment: Complicated. So his friend has already known he is on the verge of dying and he seeks one who had cursed him? In the case,I think he is not ready to accept being defeated by the curse and does not want to tell him about not being able to avoid it.

Comment: Their friends haven't found out that he was cursed, so I think that he was avoiding to tell them anything to not make them worry. I guess what he tried to say was until he found the one who cursed him, he didn't want others to know about what happened to him. That part of the dialogue sounds strange to me...

Comment: It wouldn't by any chance happen to be 知らされる instead of 知らせる, would it?

Comment: Ah, it was  知らされる! I didn't notice that I didn't write it properly! I have some issues with my keyboard and I have to use a virtual one for the keys that don't work on my laptop, plus I cannot type in Japanese except within the browser, IME keyboard/Google Input no longer works for me...

Comment: Now the quote in the title and the body of the question says "知らさせる" ("to make someone know") instead of "知らされる" (to be made to know). I hope your keyboard situation finds a solution soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without grammar analysis, close to my original interpretation in the comment, the fact that he is going to die due to the curse is more unacceptable than letting his friend know he is going to die and make them feel lament about him since he has been struggling to seek one who cursed him to die to the last.

That is to say, the defeat by him is more unbearable than his going to die, so no one wants to know he is going to lose by the enemy. I hope this interpretation matches the plot and the protagonist’s behavior.

At this point, the 知らせる to 知らされる conversion does not change my interpretation.

Comment: Oh, this seems to fit! Gosh I mulled over this line, than you for the help!